# pseudo-selector :host not "compiled"

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, webpack

I am currently migrating an AngularJs project (v1.7.5) to Angular7.
I followed the migration instructions and everything is going pretty well.

Everything?
No, because a small problem resists over and over again.

Since I come from the AngularJs world I don't use AngularCLI and had to write my Webpack configuration by hand.

**My problem:**

When I try to use the pseudo-selector ":host" in my css files, it is not transformed into "_ngSomething" in my generated output (I use the ViewEncapsulation.Emulated mode).

**My question:**

Which module (component/loader) is in charge of transforming this pseudo-selector, and how to configure it?
I tried an "ng eject" to extract the webpack config from a project based on angularCLI, but this command seems inaccessible for the moment

Here is my current css section in webpack.conf file

```
{
    test: /\.css$/, 
            use: [
                "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
                { loader: "style-loader" },
                { loader: "css-loader", options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
                { loader: "postcss-loader" },
            ]
        }
```

Thx for any help

Comment: Did you get to solve your problem?